# gpcl6 options to create a searchable pdf form

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We use gpcl6 to create pdf documents from text reports (green bar) generated on a legacy system.  The command used is this:

```
<data stream> | gpcl6 -dNOSAFE -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=test2.pdf -
```

This produces a usable pdf document with the formfeeds handled correctly and the cctl characters removed. However, the resulting pdf is not searchable and the pages are in effect images.

Is there an option for gpcl6 that will produce a searchable pdf? I have read the documentation and the only thing that looks that it might do is -sUseOCR=Always.  But this causes a segmentation fault in my version of the program (9.54.0).

As the input is ASCII 7bit text it seems unnecessary to invoke OCR.  So is there another option to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`gpcl6` using `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite` will create a searchable pdf as a default.  However, if there are any encoding instructions in the source data then the resulting pdf will not be searchable.

Encoding instructions include embedded pcl commands such as setting the page orientation or font.